# Indicar si un texto comienza y termina con la misma letra

Tags: javascript, html, string

El ejercicio consiste en pedir un texto e indicar si dicho texto comienza y termina con la misma letra o no.
El problema que estoy teniendo es que cuando la letra de comienzo y de fin del texto no son iguales igualmente se indica como que si. No me estoy dando cuenta del error que tengo.

Mi codigo HTML es el siguiente:

```
<body>
    <h2>Ejercicio 8</h2>
    <form>
        <label for="txtEj8">Ingrese texto:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtEj8"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Mostrar" id="btnEj8">
    </form>

    <p id="resultadoEj8"></p>
</body>
```

Mi codigo JS es el siguiente:

```
window.addEventListener("load", inicio);

function inicio (){
    document.querySelector("#btnEj8").addEventListener("click", MostrarEjercicio8);
}

function verificar(texto){
    for (let i=0; i< texto.length; i++){
        if (texto.charAt(0) == texto.charAt(i)) {
            mensaje = "Si comienza y termina con la misma letra"   
        }else{
            mensaje = "No comienza y termina con la misma letra"
        }
        return mensaje   
    }
}

function MostrarEjercicio8(){
    let Eltexto = (document.querySelector("#txtEj8").value).toLowerCase();

    document.querySelector("#resultadoEj8").innerHTML = verificar(Eltexto);
}
```

Agradezco ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba así:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", inicio);

function inicio (){
    document.querySelector("#btnEj8").addEventListener("click", MostrarEjercicio8);
}

function verificar(texto){
    for (let i=0; i < texto.length; i++){
      var numeroCaracteres = texto.length;
        if (texto.charAt(0) == texto.charAt(numeroCaracteres-1)) {
            mensaje = "Si comienza y termina con la misma letra"   
        }else{
            mensaje = "No comienza y termina con la misma letra"
        }
        return mensaje   
    }
}

function MostrarEjercicio8(){
    let Eltexto = (document.querySelector("#txtEj8").value).toLowerCase();

    document.querySelector("#resultadoEj8").innerHTML = verificar(Eltexto);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h2>Ejercicio 8</h2>
    <form>
        <label for="txtEj8">Ingrese texto:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtEj8"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Mostrar" id="btnEj8">
    </form>

    <p id="resultadoEj8"></p>
</body>
```

Defines la longitud de tu texto como variable `var numeroCaracteres = texto.length;` para después poder utilizarla en tu if. Le restas uno por que inicia en cero la longitud.